# Python google query with requests module, get responce in http format

Tags: python, json, http, google-app-engine, request

I want to execute a google query with requests module in python. Here is my script:

```
import requests

searchfor = 'test'
payload = {'q': searchfor, 'key': API_KEY, 'cx': SEARCH_ENGINE_ID}
link = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customesearch/v1'
r = requests.get(link, paramas=payload)
print r.content
```

and then run the script as: ./googler.py > out

and the out is in json format.

How can I get the responce in http format?

Answer (score 1):

The google api only supports [atom/Json](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview).

So you have to parse the JSON to HTML.
You maybe want to check [json package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

append something like this to your file:

```
import json
items = json.loads(r)['items']
print "<html><body>"
for item in items:
    print "<a href=" +item['url'] + ">" + item['title'] + "</a>"
print "</body></html>"
```